# check option in parted command line unavailable after unmount

Tags: parted, hddtemp

I have an external hard drive 1 TB that won't open in Windows but will open in linux...attempt to run fsck command after unmounting just outputs:
'fsck from util-linux 2.25.2'
gparted gui hangs on detecting /dev/sdb
parted command line can access the hard drive but is not accepting the check command
help me fix this please..

Comment: What file system in that external HDD?

Comment: The file system is NTFS

Comment: Tools available for Linux cannot error correct NTFS but the standard Windows tool should do it easily.

Comment: Windows detects the unlabelled drive but it wont open the hard drive.Command prompt hangs after running chkdsk on the drive letter..

Comment: It's probably defective then. We cannot help you with that.